# Using getInitialProps with HOC which also contains getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I wrapped a page with a withAuth HOC. in the same page, i also tried to call getInitialProps. if i sign in, the getInitialProps function doesn't run (though it shows that my withAuth HOC is working).

is there anyway i can make getInitialProps for the Contact Page to work and also use the withAuth HOC (which also has a getInitialProps function)?

**Contact**

```
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import { withAuth } from "../services/withAuth";

class Contact extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    console.log("@contact authenticated ", ctx);
    return {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <p>hey there</p>
        <a href="mailto:abc@gmail.com">abc@gmail.com</a>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuth(Contact);
```

**withAuth HOC**

```
import { ME } from "../graphql/queries";
import redirect from "../lib/redirect";

export const withAuth = C => {
  class AuthComponent extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
      const response = await ctx.apolloClient.query({ query: ME });
      console.log("@withAuth ", response);
      if (!response || !response.data || !response.data.me) {
        redirect(ctx, "/");
        return {
          me: null
        };
      }

      return {
        me: response.data.me
      };
    }

    render() {
      return <C {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  return AuthComponent;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Try calling `C.getInitialProps()` inside the **getInitialProps** of your HOC:

```
export const withAuth = C => {
  class AuthComponent extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
      const response = await ctx.apolloClient.query({ query: ME });

      console.log("@withAuth ", response);

      if (!response || !response.data || !response.data.me) {
        redirect(ctx, "/");
        return {
          me: null
        };
      }

      // Get component’s props
      let componentProps = {}
      if (C.getInitialProps) {
        componentProps = await C.getInitialProps(ctx);
      }

      return {
        me: response.data.me,
        ...componentProps
      };
    }

    render() {
      return <C {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  return AuthComponent;
};
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Steve! i missed out the await keyword when copying over the ctx. Thanks for your advise. I also learnt that i cannot pass the entire ctx object to the return value as it will throw a circular reference error. if i destructure the ctx and pass on only the destructured values, it works fine. Thanks for your sharing

Comment: 0

I dont understand why your getInitialProps would fire off when it's in a hoc (not in "/pages" presumably) inside the inner class that's returned.

I get that you could pass in your <c /> component and then programatically fire off that page's getInitialProps - but then putting that logic inside the HOC's getInitialProps means it's never fired off.

What am i missing here?

Comment: @NewbieAid `getInitialProps` will be invoked on any component exported from the `pages/` directory. The **Contact** component in `pages/` is not exported directly. It's wrapped with `withAuth()` so it's actually the **AuthComponent** that is exported. Therefore, the server will call `getInitialProps` on the **AuthComponent**, which then passes the props to the wrapped component, **Contact**.

Comment: @SteveHolgado interesting. Hadn't really considered that with `compose` and `withData` HOC'ing before. So if you're exporting a component, from pages, but it's wrapped in `withData` and `withAuth` etc, & then it's the result of `/hocs/with-data` that's *actually* exported? Maybe i need to read up on `compose(...` a bit more.